# SOSL from ApexController is not able to run in System Mode

Tags: apex

I have one field which is hidden from user ,but i want apexcontroller used by VF Page should be able to query that data and present that field to user. I tried using withoutSharing in class but its still not returning results. Please advise

Answer (score 2):

Without Sharing doesn't apply to field visibility/access.  It only applies to record access.  So...if I use "without sharing," I bypass restrictions on which *records* the user can see, but access to fields isn't affected.

You should be able to see the "hidden" field in your Apex class though.  Apex runs in "system mode", ignoring the object and field access settings of the user.

Comment: @David, did you figure out what was wrong? Curious about this one.